# How to derive ~(P → Q) → P?

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

My book (*An Exposition of Symbolic Logic with Kalish-Montague derivations*) asks me to derive the theorem *~(P → Q) → P*, but I have no idea how to derive it. The book gives no correction for theorems' proofs, and it doesn't tell the theorem's name, probably because it doesn't have a name.

So I ask: what is the derivation of *~(P → Q) → P* step by step?

The book, at this point, already taught *modus ponens*, *modus tollens*, double negation, repetition (A, therefore, A), direct derivation, conditional derivation, indirect derivation, subderivations, and I am not allowed to use any other theorem to prove *~(P → Q) → P*.

If it's not allowed to ask for derivations and proofs of things, please, tell me, and I delete this question.

Comment: What rules/axioms/definitions are you allowed to use? Since, technically, method of truth tables can be a proof.

Comment: @player3236, the book only gives "modus tollens", "modus ponens", "douple negation", "repetion" (A, therefore A), direct derivation, conditional derivation, indirect derivation and subderivation. Is it what you asked?

Comment: @player3236, I forgot: and no already proved theorem can be used.

Comment: @player3236, should I put this information in the question?

Comment: Sure. That makes it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a derivation using natural deduction rules from the textbook Gamut L.T.F. "Logic, language and meaning". It may help you with your derivation.

1. ¬(P→Q) - assumption
2. ¬P - assumption
3. P - assumption
4. ⊥ in 3,4
5. Q - EFSQ (explosion principle) (close assumption 3)
6. P→Q - Rule Introduction of → in 3,5
7. ⊥ in 1,6 (close assumption 2)
8. ¬¬P - Rule Introduction of ¬ in 2
9. P - Rule Elimination of ¬¬ in 8 (close assumption 1)
10. ¬(P→Q)→P - Rule Introduction of → in 1,9

Comment: @Mauro_curto, is this book good? I am asking because apparently "my book" is lacking stuff and I don't think it explains that well.

Comment: It is a realy didactic book and the syntax and semantics of propositional and predicates logics are well explained. I'm a student of philosophy and as you can appreciate in the title of the book it is an introduction to language-oriented logic. Natural deduction is realy well explained, I suggest you find out well about the book if you plan to buy it. I don't have a version in english but i can give you a spanish one if you want (I don't know if I'm allowed to do that)

Comment: @Mauro_curto, I am Brazilian, therefore, I speak Portuguese, therefore, I understand Spanish (I can't speak it, but I can understand it). But don't do it, I think you could be arrested and I can buy can one, so thanks for the knowledge of existence of this book — which I'll buy — and, please, don't give me the book, because you can be arrested for doing it.

Comment: @Mauro_curo, only one more question: if John (hypothetical person) knows 0 about logic, would you recommend this book? I mean, would you recommend it for an absolute beginner? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I recomended for beginners. I can say it's a good book because it is used in the university of Buenos Aires in LOGIC1 (as well as in La Plata). It is not a book that will teach you mathematical logic. remember to look at the index first if you want to buy it.

Comment: @Mauro_curto, thank you. I want to learn mathematical logic, so I won't buy it, but thank you again.

Comment: @Schilive I recommend the free and open textbook http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/ for learning the basics of mathematical logic

Answer (score 4):

> the book only gives "modus tollens", "modus ponens", "douple negation", "repetion" (A, therefore A), direct derivation, conditional derivation, indirect derivation and subderivation.

You are asked to derive a conditional statement, $\neg (P\to Q)~\to~ P$ so use a *conditional derivation*.   So make a *subderivation* of the consequent, $P$, under the assumption of the antecedent, $\neg(P\to Q)$.

You have no way to directly derive $P$ under that assumption, so that calls for an *indirect derivation*.  Thus make a subderivation of a *contradiction* under the assumption of the negation, $\neg P$.

Now derive a contraduction under the assumptions $\neg P$ and $\neg(P\to Q)$ will involve either deriving $P$ or $P\to Q$.  Since if you could directly derive $P$ you would not be here... You are seeking to derive the conditional statement $P\to Q$, so ...

$$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{}{\fitch{\neg (P\to Q)}{\fitch{\neg P}{~~\vdots\\P\to Q\\\bot}\\P}\\\neg(P\to Q)\to P}$$

Comment: @Graham_Kemp, thanks for the answer. I have a question: how do I derive P → Q under the assumption of ¬P and ¬(P→Q)?

Comment: Since you need P → Q, a good aproach would be to assume P and try to derivate Q. One way you can do that is by using the explosion priciple or "ex falso quodlibet" which states that if you assume a formula X and you derivate ⊥ then you can conclude X→Y (where Y is an arbitrary formula that you chose). I don`t know if you are allowed to use this priciple (I'm not familiar with some of the names of the rules you named). If you want I can post an answer using the natural deduction rules that I Know.

Comment: @Mauro_curto, if you do it, thanks, but you don't have to do it.

Comment: @Maurocurto With this system it appears explosion *may* be implemented by **indirect derivation**: When a *contradiction* can be derived in the context of several assumptions, and $\neg Q$, $~$ therefore we can infer $Q$ is derivable in the context of those assumptions (with $\neg Q$ discharged).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Start with an initial premise of $\neg (P \implies Q)$. Then apply the definition of '$\implies$'