# Prove $\vdash((\alpha\rightarrow\beta)\rightarrow\gamma)\rightarrow(\neg \gamma\rightarrow\alpha)$ in P.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-systems

Prove $\vdash((\alpha\rightarrow\beta)\rightarrow\gamma)\rightarrow(\neg \gamma\rightarrow\alpha)$ in $P$.

In propositional calculus formal system $P$, three axioms could be used:

(A1) $(\alpha\rightarrow(\beta\rightarrow\alpha))$

(A2) $((\alpha\rightarrow(\beta\rightarrow\gamma))\rightarrow((\alpha\rightarrow\beta)\rightarrow(\alpha\rightarrow\gamma)))$

(A3) $(((\neg\alpha)\rightarrow(\neg\beta))\rightarrow(\beta\rightarrow\alpha))$

I've already proved it in N, and I understand the equivalence of N and P. But I wonder how to prove the proposition directly in P using A1~A3.

Comment: Quite convoluted... You have to assume $\lnot \gamma$ (to be used finally with Dedutction Th) and assume $\lnot \alpha$ to derive $(\alpha \to \beta)$ and then $\gamma$.

Comment: Each of the axioms has an opening and closing parenthesis pair around the entire axiom. Not so the proposition you wish to prove. Intentional? Immaterial?

Comment: @coffeemath That's immaterial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given system is Jan Łukasiewicz's version. As usual in the proofs of the Hilbert-style systems, I shall employ a modular approach, reusing metatheorems and meta-rules. The metatheorems (CT and MT) and the meta-rule (TI) used below have online explanations; the following links can be referred to in order to examine them and apply the ideas into the system (MP is the rule of *modus ponens*):

- [CT](http://logic.stanford.edu/logica/homepage/hilbertarian.php?id=contrapositive) (contrapositive theorem): $(A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow(\neg B\rightarrow\neg A)$
- [MT](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3814850/754923): $\neg(A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow A$
- [TI](http://logic.stanford.edu/logica/homepage/hilbertarian.php?id=transitivity) (transitivity of implication) $A\rightarrow B, B\rightarrow C\vdash A\rightarrow C$

1. $\alpha\rightarrow(\beta\rightarrow \alpha)\tag{Axiom 1}$
2. $(\alpha\rightarrow(\beta\rightarrow \alpha))\rightarrow(\neg(\beta\rightarrow \alpha)\rightarrow\neg \alpha)\tag{CT}$
3. $\neg(\alpha\rightarrow \beta)\rightarrow \alpha\tag{MT}$
4. $(\neg(\alpha\rightarrow \beta)\rightarrow \alpha)\rightarrow(\neg \gamma\rightarrow(\neg(\alpha\rightarrow \beta)\rightarrow \alpha))\tag{Axiom 1}$
5. $\neg \gamma\rightarrow(\neg(\alpha\rightarrow \beta)\rightarrow \alpha)\tag{MP 3, 4}$
6. $(\neg \gamma\rightarrow(\neg(\alpha\rightarrow \beta)\rightarrow \alpha))\rightarrow((\neg \gamma\rightarrow\neg(\alpha\rightarrow \beta))\rightarrow(\neg \gamma\rightarrow \alpha))\tag{Axiom 2}$
7. $((\alpha\rightarrow \beta)\rightarrow \gamma)\rightarrow(\neg \gamma\rightarrow\neg(\alpha\rightarrow \beta))\tag{CT}$
8. $(\neg \gamma\rightarrow\neg(\alpha\rightarrow \beta))\rightarrow(\neg \gamma\rightarrow \alpha)\tag{MP 5, 6}$
9. $((\alpha\rightarrow \beta)\rightarrow \gamma)\rightarrow(\neg \gamma\rightarrow \alpha)\tag{TI 7, 8}$